# Is there a way to remove partial postcodes from GoogleMaps autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, jquery-ui-autocomplete, google-maps-api-2

I need to remove the partial postcode (in the red box) from the suggestions dropdown on autocomplete, so that users can only select a full postcode.

How do I achieve this or does anyone have a better suggestion?

[image: Things to remove]

I think everything works as it should but my client thinks to be able to select a partial postcode is too confusing.

This is my code:

```
let autocomplete;
let address1Field;
let postalField;

function initAutocomplete() {
  address1Field = document.querySelector("#ship-address");
  postalField = document.querySelector("#postcode");

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address1Field, {
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: ["gb"]
    },
    fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
  });
  address1Field.focus();

  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  let address1 = "";
  let postcode = "";

 
  for (const component of place.address_components) {
    const componentType = component.types[0];
    switch (componentType) {
      case "street_number":
        {
          address1 = `${component.long_name} ${address1}`;
          break;
        }
      case "route":
        {
          address1 += component.short_name;
          break;
        }
      case "sublocality_level_1":
        {
          address1 += component.long_name;
          break;
        }
      case "postal_code":
        {
          postcode = `${component.long_name}${postcode}`;
          break;
        }
      case "postal_code_suffix":
        {
          postcode = `${postcode}-${component.long_name}`;
          break;
        }
      case "postal_town":
        document.querySelector("#postal_town").value = component.long_name;
        break;
      case "locality":
        // document.querySelector("#locality").value = component.long_name;
        break;
      case "administrative_area_level_1":
        {
          // document.querySelector("#state").value = component.short_name;
          break;
        }
      case "administrative_area_level_2":
        document.querySelector("#county").value = component.long_name;
        break;
    }
  }

  address1Field.value = address1;
  postalField.value = postcode;

  document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = '<input name="latitude" type="hidden" id="latitude" value="' + place.geometry.location.lat() + '"><input name="longitude" type="hidden" id="longitude" value="' + place.geometry.location.lng() + '">';
}

window.initAutocomplete = initAutocomplete;
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, because those partial postal codes *kind of are* postal codes; they are *postal code prefixes* which is *kind of a postal code* in the Places API.

You can [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309) for Place Autocomplete to support **excluding** certain types. Such a feature would allow you to request predictions including `types=postal_code` and *excluding* `types=postal_code_prefix`.

Currently, requesting predictions with `types=postal_code` *will include* predictions with `types: ["postal_code_prefix", "postal_code"]`.

Without such a feature, the closest to the desired effect could be building your own widget, retrieve predictions using the [Place Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) and discarding those predictions with`types: ["postal_code_prefix", "postal_code"]`. There are 2 significant problems with this approach:

1. *Probably* not compliant with clause **3.2.3.(j)** of the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/): *(j) No Modifying Search Results Integrity. Customer will not modify any of the Google Maps Core Services’ search results.*. You would need to seek legal advice about this.
2. The resulting user experience would be that typing `rg1` produces only one prediction (RG1 8EQ), or possible no predictions at all.

All the above might be too much hassle considering that as soon as a blank space is added to the input (e.g. `"rg1 "`) most of the predictions will be for full precision postal codes, and as soon as an additional character is added (e.g. `"rg1 1"`) **all** the predictions will be for full precision postal codes.

This is the intended behavior, users are expected to *disambiguate* short inputs like `rg1` by adding a character, a blank space can often make a big difference.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, not the answer I was hoping for, but I guess I'll just have to allow the system to accept partial postcodes.